# Multiple CSV file Header to dB without pojo

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, opencsv

As neither number of columns nor number of files are constant.

So what is the process to store CSV file values with help of header and  with out creating pojo class for all the client files

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. add some code to make your problem more clear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For example if I use opencsv , I can use statefulbeantocsv<mapping class> . So mapping class variables and CSV header should be mapped. But If I am not sure about header, then mapping class should be generic to support dynamic header.  Then what could be the way to map unknown header with pojo class... Ex: CSV has header  I'd, name   pojo class has the variable int id, string name. I can map class with CSV with some annotations. But if I receive CSV header as I'd, name, age , then I should have age variable in pojo class.. otherwise I cant store values in pojo.

Comment: check whether entity attribute model make sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: No, I m looking for how to map CSV multiple CSV field with single pojo